# C# Merge two enumerables taking care of distinct values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

**Warning: you might need coffee before go through this**

I have a function that take care of merge two enumerables into one. Here is the code:

```
private IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, IGrouping<Tuple<string, double?>, MyClassTupleAndRow>>> MergeTwoGroupsOfKeyTypes(
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, IGrouping<Tuple<string, double?>, MyClassTupleAndRow>>> firstGroup,
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, IGrouping<Tuple<string, double?>, MyClassTupleAndRow>>> secondGroup)
        {
            // Here merge and resolve the "distinct problem"
    }
```

MyClassTupleAndRow:

```
class MyClassTupleAndRow
{
    Tuple<string, double?> Tuple;
    int Row;
}
```

I will try to summarize the problem:

I have a collection of Tuple. Each of these tuples represent a row, so I have created this `MyClassTupleAndRow` structure. These tuples are not distinct so I can have the same tuple in different rows.

I need to group the `MyClassTupleAndRow` enumerable using the tuple as key. So what I obtain is a `IGrouping<Tuple<string, double?>, MyClassTupleAndRow>>`. In this way, each element of the collection is distinct, given the Tuple as key I can see how many `MyClassTupleAndRow` classes has the same tuple.

Also that, I have more than one of these grouped collections (for reasons linked to the requirements of the program I need to create chunks of a given number of elements).

Each of the chunks of `IGrouping<Tuple<string, double?>, MyClassTupleAndRow>>` need to be grouped by the type of Tuple. For grouping, I'm using an `int` as key, I have 4 possible types of Tuple (1,2,3 and 4), depending on a condition that is not relevant here. So after grouping, I obtain a `<IGrouping<int, IGrouping<Tuple<string, double?>, MyClassTupleAndRow>>>`.

So, eventually, I have two IEnumerable of these collections.

Now the point is how can I merge two of those and let every sub-group (the grouped by Tuple one) to be a collection of distinct elements?

I mean, I can easily merge the two items in this way:

```
                var mergedWithPreviousGroup = firstGroup
                    .Union(secondGroup)
                    // Use select many to flat the groups and than regroup them using the key selector (4 groups: 1,2,3,4)
                    .SelectMany()
                    .GroupBy(/*KeySelectorHere*/);
```

But if I do it this way I will obtain a group of 4 items in which each item can contain a collection of Tuples that are not distinct.

I'm looking for a way to solve this problem.

I hope that this is clear enough, many thanks if you were able to read all the question!